# solve the recurrence relation $ T(n) = n^{1/2}T(n^{1/2}) +3n $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity, computational-mathematics

Solve the recurrence relation $ T(n) = n^{1/2}T(n^{1/2}) +3n $

My try is that:

$ T(n) = n^{1/2}T(n^{1/2}) +3n $

$ T(n) = n^{1/2}T(n^{1/4}T(n^{1/4})+3n^{1/2}) +3n $

$ . $
$ . $
$ . $

$ T(n) = n^{1-2^{-i}}T(n^{2^{-i}}) +3in $

Assume that $T(2) = 2 =>  n^{2^{-i}} = 2 => i = log(logn)$

And then $ T(n) = (n/2)T(2) + 3log(logn)n $

And from here $ T(n) = θ(nlog(logn)) $

But the issue is that $T(2) = 2 $ is not given. And I do not have any reason to assume $ T(2) = 2  $

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

With $n>0$ we have

$$
\frac{T(n)}{n} = \frac{T\left(\sqrt{n}\right)}{\sqrt{n}}+3
$$

so calling now $R(n) = \frac{T(n)}{n}$ we have the recurrence

$$
R(n) = R\left(\sqrt{n}\right)+3
$$

but

$$
R\left(2^{\log_2 n}\right) = R\left(2^{\log_2 \sqrt{n}}\right)+3
$$

and with  $\mathcal{R}(\cdot) = R\left(2^{(\cdot)}\right)$, $z = \log_2 n$ we follow with

$$
\mathcal{R}(z) = \mathcal{R}\left(\frac z2\right) +3 
$$

and now with $z = 2^u$ we follow with

$$
\mathcal{R}(2^u) = \mathcal{R}\left(2^{u-1}\right) +3 
$$

etc.